# ASP.NET MVC 5 vs Core

Tags: c#, asp.net

Порядка 3х лет работал с Winforms WPF Services и прочим по мелочи. Решил что хочу уйти в Web именно с ASP.NET(так-же есть опыт в php mysql и тд фул стэк)!

Для этих целей намереваюсь приобрести актуальную книгу для изучения материала.
Выбор пал на вот эти две от одного автора *(Адам Фримен)*

1. "*ASP.NET Core MVC с примерами на C# для профессионалов*" (2017 гв)
2. "*ASP.NET MVC 5 с примерами на C# 5.0 для профессионалов*" (2015 гв)

Т.к. я в этой серверной технологии совершенно не разбираюсь, **хотелось бы узнать что более актуально и полезно первичного понимания архитектуры ASP.NET приложения.**
(в первую очередь в голову приходят: маршрутизация, работа с кукисами, проверка входных данных, продвинутая шаблонизация, развертывание, написание безопасного от DOS кода итд)

Comment: Я бы посоветовал начать с этого https://www.asp.net/learn Но, если надо именно книгу, то по core книгу покупать бессмысленно, так как там инфа уже скорее всего не актуальная.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за Ваш совет. Хотелось бы уточнить почему Core не актуально? Из-за других назначений и +/- относительно ASP.NET MVC 5? Как я понимаю в релиз эта технология вышла в 2016 году.

Comment: Так как core - технология новая относительно, МС часто вносят в неё изменения. Я сам так попался, прочитал книгу по core - а там уже не самый свежий материал. Прошел курсы (которым всего то полгода), а в Core успели опять что то поменять. Потому не вижу смысла покупать по Core книгу, тем более что вроде скоро вторую версию обещают выпустить. https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md